# AlphaBlend and 16-bit color mode

Tags: windows, graphics, alphablending

Win32 graphics is not my gig, but I have to do some alpha blending. The following code works fine in 32-bit color mode but displays nothing except the white background in 16-bit mode. Sorry for the length, but I don't know where it's going wrong. This is as compact as I could make it.

`hbm` is a 32-bit ARGB bitmap with varying per-pixel alpha, size 16x16 (so, cx = cy = 16).

```
// Create a memory DC to construct the bits
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmMem = CreateBitmap(cx, cy, 1, 32, NULL);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);

// Fill the BG
RECT rc = { 0, 0, cx, cy };
FillRect(hdcMem, &rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

// Get the bitmap bits
BITMAPINFO bmi;
ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = cx;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = cy;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> pvBits(new BYTE[cx * cy * 4]);
GetDIBits(hdcMem, hbm, 0, cy, reinterpret_cast<void*>(pvBits.get()), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

// Premultiply all color channel values by the per-pixel alpha.
int ctPixels = cx * cy;
BYTE *prgba = pvBits.get();
for (int i = 0; i < ctPixels; ++i)
    {
    int alpha = *(prgba + 3);
    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; ++j)
        {
        int k = *prgba;
        *prgba++ = k * alpha / 255;
        }
    ++prgba;
    }

// Put the new bits back
SetDIBits(hdcMem, hbm, 0, cy, reinterpret_cast<void*>(pvBits.get()), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

// Alpha blend into memory DC
HDC hdcSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcMem);
HBITMAP hbmOld = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hdcSrc, hbm));
BLENDFUNCTION bfn = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };
AlphaBlend(hdcMem, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdcSrc, 0, 0, cx, cy, bfn);
SelectObject(hdcSrc, hbmOld);
DeleteDC(hdcSrc);

// Blit the memory DC to the screen
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, cx, cy, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

I have some vague suspicions about `CreateCompatibleDC` but other than that I'm flying blind.

Any help appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183352.aspx) per pixel alpha values are only supported with 32-bit bitmaps. `SetDIBits` converts your 32-bit DIB into a 16-bit DDB if the display using 16-bit colour, and a 16-bit DDB has no space to store alpha values. You'll have to set `bfn.SourceConstantAlpha` to your alpha value instead to get this to work. You won't need to premultiply your bitmap in that case either.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't use SourceConstantAlpha because it's not constant. The alpha varies from opaque to fully transparent (I've added this to the question). There has to be a way to do this, since we've found that WPF can.

Comment: Well, WPF doesn't use GDI, it uses Direct3D. So if switching to Direct3D is an option that will work. Otherwise I think you're going to have to it yourself. Render your window to a memory DC, get the bits, blend them and set them back.

Comment: Dang. OK, thanks for the info. Bringing in Direct3D just for this is overkill, so I guess we'll be doing our own blending.  Thanks again.